# Updating friendsofsymfony/user-bundle (dev-master 42ad073 => v2.0.0-alpha3)

Tags: symfony, composer-php, fosuserbundle

We've been using FOSUserBundle for quite sometime with great results.

We are currently on Symfony v2.8.8 and cannot upgrade to Symfony v3.x for now.

Recently in updating our production environment we received an error when executing a composer update with this command: 
`php composer.phar update`.

The error is:

`Updating friendsofsymfony/user-bundle (dev-master 42ad073 => v2.0.0-alpha3)`

`Update failed (Failed to execute git show-ref --head -d`

`sh: git: command not found)`

`Would you like to try reinstalling the package instead [yes]?`

Regardless on if we choose 'yes' or 'no' here we get:

`Removing friendsofsymfony/user-bundle (dev-master)`

`[RuntimeException]`
`Failed to execute git show-ref --head -d`
`sh: git: command not found`

Our current composer.json was set to:
`"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",`

However, we have tried a number of different versions including various v1.3 releases. Is there something else (e.g. version) we should be changing the composer.json to or somewhere else to look to get this working again?

Appreciate the input.

Comment: The error seems rather explicit "git: command not found"

Comment: @shady thanks for the guidance. We'll look to install git on that server and see if we can get beyond that error. Thanks.